# Logic and data in class

Tags: java, design-patterns

I have following classes:

```
class AbstractFruitData  {
    int size;
    int weight;
}

class FruitData extends AbstractFruitData {
    String name;
}

class AppleData extends FruitData {
    String garden;

    String getGarden() {
        return garden;
    }
}

class AbstractFruit<T extends AbstractFruitData> {
    T data;

    void setData(T data) {
        this.data = data;
    }

    T getData() {
        return data;
    }
}

class Fruit<T extends FruitData> extends AbstractFruit<AbstractFruitData> {
    String colour;
}

class Apple extends Fruit<AppleData> {
}
```

Then if i write following code:

```
Apple apple = new Apple();
apple.setData(new AppleData());
apple.getData().getGarden(); <-- error
```

Here is error because `data` is type `AbstractFruitData`. I can cast, but is it possible in Java to write code, where `setData` or `getData` methods will operate only on AppleData in compile time?

Second question: is any design pattern, where this structure of classes can be replaced by better architecture?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to convince the compiler to let you access `getGarden` by plugging in `T` into `AbstractFruit<T>` in the declaration of `Fruit`, like this:

```
class Fruit<T extends FruitData> extends AbstractFruit<T> {
    String colour; //                                  ^
}                  // Here is the change --------------+
```

Once your make this change, your class will compile and run fine ([demo on ideone](http://ideone.com/UmlZxq)).

As far as the second part of your question goes, there is no silver bullet for managing parallel class hierarchies; your approach of letting the caller pair up the class with its data is quite reasonable, because the users have complete access to both the class and to its data.

You may gain some flexibility by using interfaces in place of some of your base classes, but ultimately if two classes need to know about each other, there is no universal way of abstracting that out into a class that is higher up in the hierarchy.

Comment: Yes, that's correct :). Thanks.To second question: dividing implementation and data like this is good design?